# Extending formula down the column without symmetry

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Suppose this is the formula for my I2 cell `=IF(C2<>C1, N2, K1)`.
If I extend this formula down the I column in excel, the default behaviour is

> I3= IF(C3<>C2,N3,K2)
>
> I4= IF(C4<>C3,N4,K3)

The default behaviour is ok except for true value section of IF statement i.e N column value where my requirement is that it should be always fixed with N2 such as

> I3= IF(C3<>C2,N2,K2)
>
> I4= IF(C4<>C3,N2,K3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a $

```
=IF(C2<>C1, N$2, K1)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. A dollar sign before the row number means the row number will stay constant using copy+paste or fill. Similarly for the column number (e.g. `$N$2`).